# How can i define a bool array in VC++ with more than MAXINT Elements

Tags: c++, arrays, element

In C++ the definition

```
unsigned long long myDimension
bool myVar[myDimension];
```

is possible, also when myDimension is bigger than 0xFFFFFFFF, but the access of an element at index bigger than 0xFFFFFFFF will cause an error while runtime.

This was my error message: Ausnahmefehler bei 0x00007FF7CACD01DC in Multiply.exe: Vom RangeChecks-Instrumentationscode wurde ein Arrayzugriff außerhalb des Bereichs erkannt.

So my Question is how to write a own class which behaves like a normal array and can handle more elements.

Error prone code:

```
bool vergleichsMintherme[0x1000000000]; 
main()
{
    vergleichsMintherme[0x100000000] = false;
}
```

Comment: Arrays elements are contiguous so you will need `sizeof(element) * 0xFFFFFFFF` memory available to you.  Have you thought about using a `std::map` or other associative container instead?

Comment: @Richard Critten: I did think about using other containers. I thought about vector, sets and maps. But for my problem the array is the most performant solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class largeBoolArray
{
private:
    bool **myMintherms;
    unsigned long long dim;
    unsigned int dimPointers;
public:
    largeBoolArray()
    {
        myMintherms = NULL;
        dim = 0;
        dimPointers = 0;
    };
    largeBoolArray(unsigned long long Dim)
    {
        assert(Dim > 0);
        dim = Dim;
        dimPointers = ((unsigned int) (Dim & 0xFFFFFFFF80000000) >> 31) + 1;
        myMintherms = new bool*[dimPointers];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimPointers; i++)
        {
            while (dim > 0)
            {
                if (dim > 0x80000000)
                {
                    myMintherms[i] = new bool[0x80000000];
                    for (unsigned long long j = 0ll; j < 0x7fffffff; j++)
                        myMintherms[i][j] = false;
                    dim -= 0x80000000;
                }
                else
                {
                    myMintherms[i] = new bool[dim];
                    for (unsigned long long j = 0ll; j < dim; j++)
                        myMintherms[i][j] = false;
                    dim = 0;
                }
            }
            dim = Dim;
        }
    }
    ~largeBoolArray()
    {
        if (myMintherms != NULL)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimPointers; i++)
            {
                if (myMintherms[i] != NULL)
                delete[] myMintherms[i];
            }
            delete[] myMintherms;
        }
    }
    bool& operator[] (unsigned long long selektor)
    {
        unsigned int firstIndex = (unsigned int)(selektor & 0xFFFFFFFF80000000) >> 31;
        unsigned int secondIndex = (selektor & 0x7FFFFFFF);
        return myMintherms[firstIndex][secondIndex];
    }
    largeBoolArray operator= (largeBoolArray o1)
    {
        this->dim = o1.dim;
        this->dimPointers = o1.dimPointers;
        this->myMintherms = new bool*[dimPointers];
        unsigned long long dimRest;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dimPointers; i++)
        {
            dimRest = dim;
            while (dimRest > 0)
            {
                if (dimRest > 0x80000000)
                {
                    this->myMintherms[i] = new bool[0x80000000];
                    for (unsigned long long j = 0ll; j < 0x7fffffff; j++)
                        this->myMintherms[i][j] = o1.myMintherms[i][j];
                    dimRest -= 0x80000000;
                }
                else
                {
                    this->myMintherms[i] = new bool[dimRest];
                    for (unsigned long long j = 0ll; j < dimRest; j++)
                        this->myMintherms[i][j] = o1.myMintherms[i][j];
                    dimRest = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }
    void clear()
    {
        for (unsigned long long i = 0ll; i < dim; i++)
            (*this)[i] = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I realize it has some slightly strange behavior, but why not just use `std::vector<bool>`?

Comment: because of the mentioned problem. I encountered also problems with big indexes. What strange behaviour you mean in concrete?

Comment: It is exactly answering the question. The questioner asked for a class to work around the problem. And thats it.

Comment: There are countless memory leaks in the snippet.

Comment: @Passer: Where do you see one? In my opinion the destructor deletes all allocated memory of the object.

Comment: Look at your destructor again, you're just doing `delete *boolMintherms;` in a loop. Repeatedly calling `delete` with the same pointer obviously isn't correct. Why does each subarray have a size of `Dim`? Shouldn't they be smaller since you're attempting to divide a large allocation into smaller chunks? You also seem to be mixing up `boolMyBoolArrays` and `boolMintherms`, which is it? You didn't test any of this did you?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Thanks, you are right. I fixed it. I did a test. But i do not want to give my original code, so i made a few changes before post.

Comment: You're still leaking the outermost array allocation. You need `delete[] boolMyBoolArrays;` after the loop. You also need to say `delete[] boolMyBoolArrays[i];` (note the brackets) inside the loop because you used the array form of `new` when allocating them.

Comment: Thanks again. Now I think the answer can be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

1. you must compile in 64bit mode, in 32bit your program just doesn't have the address space to fit such an array
2. you must allocate the array on the heap, if you make it a global array the executable will be too large and if you allocate on the stack you will overflow the stack
3. You need to be careful and only pass array index values in size_t variables not int

other then that C++ supports access to large memory blocks just fine.

Here is old-C-style array allocation that works (tested on VC2017):

```
 int* reallyLargeArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*0x100000002);
 reallyLargeArray[0x100000001] = 5;
```

std::vector also works

```
  std::vector<int> reallyLargeArray;
  reallyLargeArray.resize(0x100000002);
  reallyLargeArray[0x100000001] = 5;
```

C++ style allocation (new int[0x100000002]) does not work,

Comment: I used new instead, all the other conditions where met. Not in the example but in the real program.

Comment: @SchwertAs new does not work, but std::vector and malloc both work with no problems

Comment: If I used your second code the program stops with a breakpoint with the following message: "vector<bool> iterator not dereferencable" (i used bool instead of int)

Comment: 0x100000000 == 4294967296

Comment: @SchwertAs you are right, std::vector<bool> crushes, however std::vector<int> and std::vector<char> work, that smells like undefined behavior so I suggest not using std::vector for this, I believe the malloc solution is safe